# Cannot display special characters in HTML

Tags: html

I can not display special characters on my website!

I try to type this: Ḍøøӽ(My clan name), and I get nothing!

And yea I add other elements.. But is there that I'm doing wrong? Can I use some generator or something like this?

Thanks for help :)

PS: My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>DooxNames</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="tools/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="tools/960.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Copse_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Gabriola_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1', {fontFamily: 'Copse', hover:true})
    Cufon.replace('p.info', {fontFamily: 'Gabriola', hover:true})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="shim"></div>
<div id="content">
    <h1 class="logo"><span class="one">Doox Fennon</span><span class="two">Ḍøøӽ║ᶂeȠȠØŅ</span></h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your html. It generates the text perfectly in an Ubuntu Apache installation. Most probably there is something wrong with how you serve the page or with your browser.

Comment: Yea, that's right that's why I submitted this here...Can i upload this to my website so you can maybe see it better or something?

Comment: Hmm. clandoox.ee.tn/thanksmate.html

Comment: First i saw normal text in Arial and than it changed to Copse..Maybe is font problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the html entity values instead. I used http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html to translate Ḍøøӽ║ᶂeȠȠØŅ to `&#x1e0c;&oslash;&oslash;&#x04fd;&#x2551;&#x1d82;e&#x0220;&#x0220;&Oslash;&#x0145;`

Comment: Also, note that the Notepad++ textFX plugin will do the same thing.

Comment: Try putting non-special chars in the same place. I bet they don't render either. Look at your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was found by me, with assistance of other helpers(thanks!)

Problem was in this line of html:

```
    Cufon.replace('h1', {fontFamily: 'Copse', hover:true})
```

That line changed fontFamily inside of h1 to Copse, which couldn't display special characters.

When that line was removed, font was Arial, and ofc, Arial can display special characters.

Comment: You can also use the fonts you like by editing css styles. Copse font is available from Google font api, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must put a html symbol instead... i.e to display a ø you need to type

`&#8709;`
this link can be useful http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp